Is $\sum_{k = 0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} \left(-\frac14\right)^k\binom{n - k}k = \frac{n + 1}{2^n}$ a recognised identity?
Does anyone recognise this identity of binomial coefficients?
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} \left(-\frac14\right)^k\binom{n - k}k = \frac{n + 1}{2^n}$$
I came across it as a special case of a rather complicated expression for a derivative.

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., here, here, here and here.

Yes, the identity is proved at art of problem solving, in the second answer on $f(n)$.

This question is similar to: finite sum with combinatorics. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

See the linked question and answer for $g(n)$, where $2n$ can be replaced with $n$ to obtain your identity.  Note also the combinatorial proof provided there.

Here is the solution from art of problem solving. Let
$$
f(n)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)^k 2^{n} \binom{n-k}{k}.
$$
Substitututing $z=-\frac{1}{4}$, we obtain
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f(n)x^n&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} z^k \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{n-k}{k} (2x)^n\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (4x^2z)^k \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{n+k}{k} (2x)^n\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(4x^2z)^k}{(1-2x)^{k+1}}=\frac{1}{1-2x} \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{4x^2z}{1-2x}\right)^k\\
&=\frac{1}{1-2x} \cdot \frac{1}{1-\frac{4x^2z}{1-2x}}=\frac{1}{1-2x-4x^2z}
\end{align*}
Now, this is where it starts being ugly for arbitrary $z$, but fortunately the value $z=-\frac{1}{4}$ behaves quite nice:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f(n)x^n=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)x^n$$
Hence
$$
f(n)=n+1.
$$
